# How does physical distance between processor and memory/cache affect data transfer speeds

Tags: memory, cpu, computer-architecture, clockspeed

The L1 cache is situated inside the cpu to speed up the process of data access but since electrical signals travel at the speed of light(almost constant) which is blazingly fast then how does distance come into consideration.
 For light to travel a distance of 2 cm vs a distance of 10cm won't be a great deal and time taken to reach both the points would be almost be the same, then why is it said that, the closer the component is to the cpu the faster the cpu can access it. 
 Another question is that, What is **clock speed** of a cpu and how does it affect data transfer speeds.

Comment: You hit it: it's the speed of light thing, or, really, the speed of electricity in copper (about 1/3 the speed of light). You need to understand how incredibly fast processors are now,, and the latency between a request and response doubles the distance.

Comment: But still at a speed 1/3rd of light 2-10 cm wont matter much .

Comment: It does. Do the math, and remember to double the distance.

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob at these things. Please help :)

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal - Help you with what exactly?  You state that the distance does not matter, except it does, so your question on its fundamentals is based on your incorrect understand of a core concept.

Comment: @Ramhound yes my incorrect understanding might be the reason for my fuzziness. My direct question is that "IS DISTANCE ALSO A DECIDING FACTOR FOR DATA TRANSFER SPEEDS BETWEEN CPU AND CACHE/MEMORY ?" even though data transfers at almost speed of light.

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal - Yes;

Comment: How then ?(which was my original question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a microprocessor cache, [resistive-capacitive delay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant#Delay) is significant. As Wikipedia notes, this delay is proportional to the square of length. To reduce this delay, repeaters can be inserted, but these add *logic* delay. Another (lesser) delay factor is in address decoding; each doubling of size requires one more row decoder to address the appropriate row of bits.